# How can I print a Python class?

Tags: python, class

I have a class that contains several functions(most of it contains code that parses smth., get all necessary info and print it). I'm trying to print a class but i get smth. like **<_*main*_.TestClass instance at 0x0000000003650888>**. Code sample:

```
from lxml import html
import urllib2
url = 'someurl.com'


class TestClass:

    def testFun(self):
        f = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        #some code

        print 'Value for ' +url+ ':', SomeVariable

    def testFun2(self):
        f2 = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        #some code

        print 'Value2 for ' +url+ ':', SomeVariable2

test = TestClass()
print test
```

When i print functions out of class - all is ok. What i'm doing wrong and how can I print a class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour. Python can't know how the class is represented unless you define a `__str__` or `__repr__` method to give the class a string representation.

To be clear: `__repr__` is usually defined to produce a string that can be evaluated back into a similar object (in your case, `TestClass()`). The default `__repr__` prints out the `<__main__.TestClass instance at 0xdeadbeef>` thing you see.

Example `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__ + '()' # put constructor arguments in the ()
```

`__str__` can be defined to produce a human-readable "description" of the class. If not supplied, you get `__repr__`.

Example `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "(TestClass instance)"
```

Comment: `0xdeadbeef` if you hit this memory location Ill buy you a stake

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to print an instance of the class rather than the class itself. Define a `__str__` or `__repr__` method that returns a string to be used when printing the instance.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

Comment: Thanks for the answer and additional info!